# How can I monitor user input with getchar

Tags: c

I need to get a user input and check if it is a valid input.
The input must:

- Start with `space`(may be multiple) or a number.
- (Assuming condition one satisfied) After the number there may be any kind of characters as long as I manage to extract the number

#### Clarification for number valid values:

- Can be multiple digit
- Can't be negative number
- Can't contain decimal point
- Can't be scientific notation
- Can't be hexadecimal

So I wrote this basic code which simply gets the input but I have no clue on where to start on applying these conditions

```
    printf("Enter size of input:\n");
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF){
        printf("%c",c);
    }
```

For example :

- Input -     `4#@2311413sadokalda` ; expected output - `4`
- Input - `!4a` ; expected output - `Invalid Size`

Comment: You could start by checking the value of `c`. And you should invert `'\n'` and `EOF` in the while condition

Comment: @RuudHelderman edited post for clarification

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Apparently you meant to say: a number is a sequence of one or more digits. Please note that such a formal definition is already half of the solution, because it maps straight to (part of) a state machine like the one proposed by kiran Biradar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have state machine as below.

```
printf("Enter size of input:\n");
int c;
int state = 0; //0 = space, 1 = number, 2 = number read
int number = 0;
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF){
    switch(state)
    {
       case 0:
          if (isdigit(c))
            state = 1;
          else if (c == ' ')
            break;
          else
             //error
           break;

       case 1:
         if (isdigit(c))
         {
            number = number*10 + (c-'0');
            break;
         }
         else {
            state = 2;
         }

       case 2:
        printf ("%d\n",number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit complicated? `strtol` would do the job more or less.

Comment: Hello @Jabberwocky I agree, I wanted to show OP conventional method. Maybe you could make good answer on that point.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  printf("Enter size of input:\n");

  char input[100];
  fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);

  if (!isdigit(input[0]))
  {
    printf("Invalid Size\n");
  }
  else
  {
    int inputsize = strtol(input, NULL, 10);
    printf("%d\n", inputsize);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the problem statement you have given, i think this should give you your desired output

EDITED (After a few clarifications):

```
int main()
{
   int c;
   int i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF)     
    {
       if(isdigit(c) || (char)c==' ')   //isdigit() function check if given variable is a digit
        {    printf("%c",c);   
             i+=1;
        }
       else
        {   
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==0)
    {   printf("Invalid size"); }
}
```

Comment: The number can be a multiple digit and it can start with multiple spaces before the first digit

Comment: @bobthebuilder it doesn't do what the OP wants. Especially your code doesn't handle numbers with more that one digit.

Comment: @Jabberwocky this was the output i got when i used this code (for multiple digits):  I/P:  345hfdgfd
O/P: 345

Comment: @bobthebuilder formally your code does what the OP wants, but he certainly needs the actual size sooner or later. And your code doesn't get the actual size, it just printf the digits.